# Unix timestamp time is not saving to DB

Tags: 7, datetime

I am trying to use Unix timestamp for my date field.

According to the [php.net/date](http://php.net/date) U is for Unix timestamp, so this is how I set it up:

[image]

[image]

When I put an Unix timestamp time, such as the current time, 1451362409 and save. It says, "Article X has been updated", but when I go to edit, the field is empty.

For Field Type, I tried using

- Date
- Date (Unix timestamp)
- Date (ISO format)

Hence test 1, test 2, test 3.

As you can see in test 4, when it's non Unix timestamp, it is saving to the DB.

Why is it not saving to the DB? Did I miss a step, or I'm I doing something wrong? Could it be a bug? Is there any other way of doing this?