# Feeds import EU date

Tags: feeds

I try to import a csv (or excel with feeds_xls) with a title-, date- and body field in Drupal 7. The date has a calendar widget

When imported the date is empty. I think because of the difference in notation:

English: `Y/m/d H:i`
Belgian: `d/m/Y H:i`

My client has to be able to use the Belgian (EU) notation. He or she puts it in the .csv like this:

`d/m/Y`

for example: 19th of August 2016 becomes a string:

`'16/8/2016'`

I have tried the following steps:
- `dev`-version of the feeds_tamper module
- tried the `feeds_tamper-str_to_time_with_custom_format_plugin-2631092-1.patch`
- tried the `strtotime` plugin of the feeds_tamper module
- wrote a custom plugin that tries to convert the string
- tried a text-widget

The closest I get is what I think is the original item:

`array(
  'TITEL' => 'Test',
  'DATUM' => '41671',
  'BESCHRIJVING' => 'test',
)`

that is the right date (DATUM). Can anyone shine a light on this for me?

Comment: Create a custom tamper plugin and do it like this: [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy#2487938)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have added the code. Watchdog seems fine, I get a timestamp <code>1455231600</code>. But the field of the node stays empty... . What did I forget?

Comment: you need to save it in the format your date field is on. Ex: `Y/m/d`

Comment: Hi, the date field is Date (Unix)

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be a bug that doesn't allow unix timestamp date fields to save to the DB, see [Unix timestamp time is not saving to DB](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185191/epoch-time-is-not-saving-to-db)

Comment: NS, thank you so much for your info. Is there a way that I can use dates (because I have to order them in a view) with feeds?

Comment: NS, I don't know how but I got it working... . With a date-type